# Evaluating a function with a well-defined value at x,y=0

Tags: python, numpy, math

I am trying to write a program that uses an array in further calculations. I initialize a grid of equally spaced points with NumPy and assign a value at each point as per the code snippet provided below. The function I am trying to describe with this array gives me a division by 0 error at x=y and it generally blows up around it. I know that the real part of said function is bounded by `band_D/(2*math.pi)`
at x=y and I tried manually assigning this value on the diagonal, but it seems that points around it are still ill-behaved and so I am not getting any right values. Is there a way to remedy this? [This is how the function looks like with matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvkCm.png)

```
gamma=5
band_D=100
Dt=1e-3
x = np.arange(0,1/gamma,Dt)
y = np.arange(0,1/gamma,Dt)
xx,yy= np.meshgrid(x,y)
N=x.shape[0]
di = np.diag_indices(N)

time_fourier=(1j/2*math.pi)*(1-np.exp(1j*band_D*(xx-yy)))/(xx-yy)
time_fourier[di]=band_D/(2*math.pi)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a classic `0 / 0` problem. It's not really Numpy's job to figure out to apply De L'Hospital and solve this for you...  I see, as other have commented, that you had the right idea with trying to set the limit value at the diagonal (where `x` approx `y`), but by the time you'd hit that line, the warning had already been emitted (just a warning, BTW, not an exception).

For a quick fix (but a bit of a fudge), in this case, you can try to add a small value to the difference:

```py
xy = xx - yy + 1e-100
num = (1j / 2*np.pi) * (1 - np.exp(1j * band_D * xy))
time_fourier = num / xy
```

This also reveals that there is something wrong with your limit calculation... (`time_fourier[0,0]` approx `157.0796...`, not `15.91549...`).

[image]

and not `band_D / (2*math.pi)`.

For a correct calculation:

```py
def f(xy):
    mask = xy != 0
    limit = band_D * np.pi/2
    return np.where(mask, np.divide((1j/2 * np.pi) * (1 - np.exp(1j * band_D * xy)), xy, where=mask), limit)

time_fourier = f(xx - yy)
```

Comment: Yep, that solved it! Also the limit miscalculation was just a typo with the parentheses! Thanks for the input :D

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing by x-y, that will definitely throw an error when x = y. The function being well behaved here means that the Taylor series doesn't diverge. But python doesn't know or care about that, it just calculates one step at a time until it reaches division by 0.

You had the right idea by defining a different function when x = y (ie, the mathematically true answer) but your way of applying it doesn't work because the correction is AFTER the division by 0, so it never gets read. This, however, should work

```
def make_time_fourier(x, y):
    if np.isclose(x, y):
        return band_D/(2*math.pi)
    else:
        return (1j/2*math.pi)*(1-np.exp(1j*band_D*(x-y)))/(x-y)


time_fourier = np.vectorize(make_time_fourier)(xx, yy)
print(time_fourier)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.divide` with `where` option.

```py
import math

gamma=5
band_D=100
Dt=1e-3
x = np.arange(0,1/gamma,Dt)
y = np.arange(0,1/gamma,Dt)
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
N = x.shape[0]
di = np.diag_indices(N)

time_fourier = (1j / 2 * np.pi) * (1 - np.exp(1j * band_D * (xx - yy)))
time_fourier = np.divide(time_fourier,
                         (xx - yy),
                         where=(xx - yy) != 0)
time_fourier[di] = band_D / (2 * np.pi)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reformulate your function so that the division is inside the (numpy) sinc function, which handles it correctly.
To save typing I'll use D for band_D and use a variable

```
z = D*(xx-yy)/2
```

Then

```
T = (1j/2*pi)*(1-np.exp(1j*band_D*(xx-yy)))/(xx-yy)
= (2/D)*(1j/2*pi)*( 1 - cos( 2*z) - 1j*sin( 2*z))/z
= (1j/D*pi)* (2*sin(z)*sin(z) - 2j*sin(z)*cos(z))/z
= (2j/D*pi) * sin(z)/z * (sin(z) - 1j*cos(z))
= (2j/D*pi) * sinc( z/pi) * (sin(z) - 1j*cos(z))
```

numpy defines

```
sinc(x) to be sin(pi*x)/(pi*x)
```

I can't run python do you should chrck my calculations
The steps are

Substitute the definition of z and expand the complex exp

Apply the double angle formulae for sin and cos

Factor out sin(z)

Substitute the definition of sinc